# How to retrieve date fields in local timezone mongo with find function

Tags: mongodb, date, datetime

When I look for info in my collection

```
db.getCollection('dectar_driver_connection_log').find({})
```

I get dates in UTC:

[image]

which parameter should I add to programmatically get dates in local timezone, because mongo stores it in UTC?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-time-data/) said

> Applications that must operate or report on some unmodified local time
>   value may store the time zone alongside the UTC timestamp, and compute
>   the original local time in their application logic.

(You can also find an example in JavaScript there)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using serialization option,
e.g.in C#

```
public class Model {
        public String Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTimeProperty { get; set; }
    }

 var localTimeOption = new DateTimeSerializationOptions { Kind = DateTimeKind.Local };
            BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Model>(cm => {
                cm.MapIdProperty(c => c.Id);
                cm.MapProperty(c => c.Name);
                cm.MapProperty(c => c.DateTimeProperty)
                    .SetSerializationOptions(localTimeOption);
            });
```

and then

```
var query = Query.EQ("_id", m1.Id);
            var m2 = collection.FindOne(query);
Console.Log(m2.DateTimeProperty.ToShortTimeString());
```